# NoReverseMatch for simple Django View

Tags: python, django

I get a NoReverseMatch Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /verfahrensverzeichnis/verzeichnis/320/

Reverse for 'verfahrenvorlage' with arguments '(320,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['verfahrensverzeichnis/verfahren/vorlage/(?P<pk>[\\d+])/add/$']
```

For a fairly simple view and I can't figure out what went wrong here.
Could you help me out?

url.py:

```
url(r'^verfahren/vorlage/(?P<pk>[\d+])/add/$',
    views.verfahrenvorlage,
    name='verfahrenvorlage',
    ),
```

view.py:

```
def verfahrenvorlage(request, pk):

vorlagen = ProcedurTemplate.objects.all()
kunde_pk = pk

return render(request, 'verfahrensverzeichnis/vorlagen_auswahl.html', {'vorlagen': vorlagen, 'kunden_pk': kunde_pk})
```

from the template.py:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url 'verfahrensverzeichnis:verfahrenvorlage' verfahrensverzeichnis.customer.pk %}">Verfahren hinzufügen</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Does `r'^verfahren/vorlage/(?P<pk>\d+)/add/$'` work?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your regex:

```
(?P<pk>[\d+])
```

Including the `+` in the square brackets means you are matching "one digit or plus sign", instead of "more than one digit".

It should be

```
(?P<pk>[\d]+)
```

Or, in this case you can drop the square brackets.

```
(?P<pk>\d+)
```

Comment: Right - That worked. I debugging it for about an hour now... Thanks!